# Twitter-Bootstrap buttons retains hover state after click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I can't get my buttons to revert to their initial state after they have been clicked.

I want the button and button text to change colour when I roll over and then go back to the way it was immediately after I click.

Here's the HTML for the button:

```
<a href="#portfolio" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Portfolio</a>
```

and the CSS:

```
section.bg-image .btn-primary {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

section.bg-image .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #6699cc;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button is not reverting back after click because you have the same styles for `:focus` as you do for `:hover` and `:active`. `:focus` is applied when the element is selected (e.g. clicked in, focused, tabbed into via a keyboard, etc.) and remains in place until another element is selected.

Also: the behavior you describe *specifically* isn't quite possible with CSS; you can't have stuff happen on `:hover` and then have it end on click. `:hover` styles will always apply until you are no longer hovering over the element. So if you want styles to apply only until mouseUp event, you need to put those styles on the `:active` pseudo-class.

```css
.btn-primary {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #6699cc;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#portfolio" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Portfolio</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my hyperlinked buttons! There's still something going wrong with the button that triggers a scroll down the page, though. Is there something I need to do differently for buttons that link to anchors rather than hyperlinks?

It's the button at the top of this page if you want to take a look? www.rickymooney.net

Comment: @RikMon23 I'm not sure what's not working about the anchor links; they seem to work fine to me. What behavior are you expecting that they aren't exhibiting?

Comment: When I scroll back up after clicking the 'portfolio' button I want the button to have reset to it's original state. The weird thing is, when you click any of the 'about me', 'what I do' links in the top left, the 'portfolio button gets reset. Is there a way to reset the button after it has been clicked?

Comment: @RikMon23 I'm afraid I don't follow. For me on both mobile view and desktop view, your relevant anchor links have blue text when you are viewing that section of the page,and whenever you scroll up to the top, the links no longer have blue text, as I would expect. From my POV, the links seem to be working fine (resetting to their original state). Try running your project on a new browser to see if you're experiencing caching issues.

Comment: It works in Safari but does what I described in Chrome and Firefox. Are you on a pc or mac? I'm on a mac... Don't worry if you can't help any further. Thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: @RikMon23 I'm on a Windows 7 machine using Firefox. I know that several browser vendors have capitulated to macOS-style UX controls in order to provide a "more seamless experience between web browsing and general OS use", basically. There's not much you can do unless you hijack the events with JavaScript. Best of luck!